# AWS Bedrock - Not able to get access - Error - Operation not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-bedrock

Getting error while requesting AWS Bedrock models access. I am logged in as an admin of AWS account.[image]

I have even tried with creating another IAM user and attaching Bedrock full access policy, still not working.

Comment: In which region are you trying to access those models? These models are not provided in every region.

Comment: Ah as you are already using the UI I guess you are already in the right region as the UI only displays models which are available in the selected region.
Did you have a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/model-access.html

Comment: Yes I did follow that, but in vain. @bitcloud

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. When I opened the developer mode in the browser, I noticed that before sending a request, an error about a missing use case form popped up, which triggered an "operation not allowed" error. However, when applying for models other than Claude, there's nowhere to fill in a use case. I think this is a bug in the AWS system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).